# reduce redux-thunk boilersplate code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm using redux-thunk middleware, it handles but async action well but I have too many boilerplate to write, how can I reduce it?

```
export function userReducer(state = {
  signup_loading: false,
  signup_failed: '',
  signup_error: '',
  login_loading: false,
  login_failed: '',
  login_error: ''
}, { payload, payload: { data, error } }) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SIGNUP_REQUEST:
      return {
        signup_loading: true
      }
    case SIGNUP_SUCCESS:
      return {
        signup_loading: false,
        data
      }
    case SIGNUP_FAILED:
      return {
        signup_loading: false,
        signup_error: error
      }
    case LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return {
        login_loading: true
      }
    case LOGIN_SUCESS:
      return {
        login_loading: false,
        data
      }
    case LOGIN_FAILED:
      return {
        login_loading: false,
        login_error: error
      }
    default: return state
  }
}
```

There are similar things that I want to do for each http call in the entire app:

- before request I want to show loader for every http call
- hide the loader after it’s finished
- if error stop the loader and show the error msg

no way I want to copy paste above code across all the reducer

Answer (score 0):

You can keep seperate actions like, SHOW_LOADER, HIDE_LOADER for handling the loader. These actions can be dispatched when you make a web api call, or when an api call return. These actions can be dispatched from anywhere in your application to handle the loader states. You will have to write that only in one reducer which can be called from anywhere.

Comment: how do you do namespacing for those loader? show loader for every actions doesn't work, coz in a page you might have multiple http call, eg. you load feeds, load notification, load comments..

Comment: Are they seperate or same loader? If they are to handle same loader icon, you can keep a counter, increment the counter when an api is called and decrement when it returns, now u can hide the loader if the counter is 0

Comment: I can use one loading for example above but it won't work, if you have 2 pages, one for sign up one for login, you can't use one loading state. Why? coz you might be navigating around and might have clash if u use one loading state, that's why I seperate them into signup_loading, login_loading etc